# pH Level - Keeps Returning Same Answer

Tags: java, class, while-loop, boolean

i am making a program where users can enter a number between **0-14**. I currently have 2 class. One is used for the calculations & the other is for the main(Where the program runs).

**Calculations**

public class phcalculations {

```
public static final double MIN = -0.999;
public static final double stronglyAcidic =0;
public static final double acidic =2.1;
public static final double weaklyAcidic =4.1;
public static final double nearNeutralAcid =6.1;
public static final double Neutral =7;
public static final double nearNeutralBase=7.01;
public static final double weaklyAlkaline=8.1;
public static final double alkaline=10.1;
public static final double stronglyAlkaline=12.1;
public static final double MAX = 12.11;

//finds id double is acceptable

public phcalculations(double pH){
    //---Not valid pH
    if (pH < MIN || pH > MAX){
    System.out.println(pH +" is not a vaild pH");
    } else{
        myValue = pH;
    }


}




//method for finding pH

public String label(){
    //---Not valid pH
    if (myValue < stronglyAcidic || myValue > stronglyAlkaline){
        return "Error";
    //---Strongly Acidic 0-2
    } else if(myValue>stronglyAcidic){
        return "Strongly Acidic";
    //---Acidic 2.1-4.0 
    } else if (myValue > acidic ){
        return "Acidic";
    //---Weakly Acidic 4.1-6.0
    } else if (myValue> weaklyAcidic){
        return "Weakly Acidic"; 
    //---Near neutral   6.1-6.99
    } else if (myValue >nearNeutralAcid){
        return "Near Neutral";
    //--Neutral 7
    } else if (myValue == Neutral){
        return "Neutral";
    //---Near Neutral 7.01 -8
    } else if (myValue > nearNeutralBase){
        return "Near Neutral";
    //---Weakly Acidic 8.1-10
    } else if (myValue> weaklyAlkaline){
        return "Weakly Acidic";
    //---Alkaline 10.1-12.0
    } else if (myValue > alkaline){
        return "Alkaline";
    //---Strongly Acidic 12.1-14
    } else if (myValue>stronglyAlkaline){
        return "strongly Alkaline";
    } else {
        return "error";
    }


}


private double myValue;
```

}

---

**Main**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class pHMain {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean done =false;
    while (!done){
        System.out.println("Enter pH: ");
        double pHInput = kbd.nextDouble();
        if(pHInput < phcalculations.MIN ){
            done =true;
        } else{
            phcalculations ph = new phcalculations(pHInput);
            System.out.println("pH level is ---> " + ph.label());
        }
    }







}
```

}

---

How come when ever I run the program it returns "Strongly Acidic"

Help is appreciated. 
Thanks

**This is written in java**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `label` method's logic is incorrect.  Your second condition:

```
} else if(myValue>stronglyAcidic){
```

covers all possible values you have left.  You need to test for a specific range bounded on both sides, rather than the one-sided range you have.  Try

```
} else if(myValue > stronglyAcidic && myValue < acidic){
```

The rest of your conditions except for the last one need similar replacements, e.g.

```
} else if (myValue > acidic && myValue < weaklyAcidic){
```

Additionally, because your `stronglyAlkaline` value isn't the maximum value considered, your first condition will miss all `"Strongly alkaline"` values.  Try:

```
if (myValue < stronglyAcidic || myValue > MAX){
```

... where `MAX` should probably be `14` instead of `12.11`, based on your requirements.

Comment: Shouldn't either it be `myValue >= acidic` or just remove the whole boolean expression as it is in an `else if` and it is implied from the above checks that `myValue >= acidic` already?

Comment: @M.Shaw Yes, these conditions should account for the possibility that the pH value might be exactly a boundary value, so `>=` (or `<=` on the high end for alkaline values) is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is off. It will always be greater than stronglyAcidic and so the first real if test (not the error if test) will always be true. Solution, modify that first else-if

```
if (myValue < stronglyAcidic || myValue > stronglyAlkaline){
    return "Error";
//---Strongly Acidic 0-2
} else if(myValue > stronglyAcidic && myValue < weaklyAcidic) {
   ...
```

The take home point though is that you need to mentally walk through your code logic in such situations, just as if you were the JVM and to see what your code will be doing at each line.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `myValue == 8`. When you do:

```
} else if(myValue>stronglyAcidic){
    return "Strongly Acidic";
//---Acidic 2.1-4.0 
} else if (myValue > acidic ){
    return "Acidic";
//---Weakly Acidic 4.1-6.0
} // etc.
```

The first `if` will check if `8 > 0` and will return `"Strongly Acidic"` as a result. For this reason it will never check the second, or any other condition.

To solve this, you could invert the order of your conditions, to check from the more specific, higher values, down to the less specific, lower values:

```
} else if (myValue > stronglyAlkaline) {
    // this should be the first condition
    return "strongly Alkaline";
} else if (myValue > alkaline) {
    // this should be the second condition
    return "Alkaline";
} // and so on until

...

} else if(myValue > stronglyAcidic) {
    // and the last condition
    return "Strongly Acidic";
}
```

So if, for example, `myValue == 11`, the first condition (`11 > 12.1`) would be `false`, but the second condition (`11 > 10.1`) would be `true` and it would return `"Alkaline"`.